# How to Debug Outlook Add-in in the Android app?

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

Does anyone have any idea how to correctly debug an **Outlook Add-in in the Android app**? For some reason, my add-in works everywhere (Windows, Mac, iOS, and Web) except on Android and I have no idea how to collect some logs at least. I have a physical Android device, but I can't find any guides or documentation on how to debug it.

Here's the manifest for the add-in: https://attacksimulator-plugins.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/outlook/manifest-dist.xml

Comment: Can you please share the manifest file? Is the add-in visible and not working or the add-in doesn't show up on Android devices at all?

Comment: The add-in is visible, it loads when tapped on it, but i think there are problems accessing the email data, as no email information is displayed. I can't figure out what's wrong, because i don't know how to debug on android or access any logs. I've posted the manifest in the main post.

Answer (score 0):

Using remote JavaScript debugging tools is the recommended way to debug web add-ins on mobile devices.

Below are some of the examples.

1. http://vorlonjs.com/documentation/#introduction
2. https://remotejs.com/ or https://trackjs.com/
3. https://jsconsole.com/remote-debugging

If your application is based on Node.js, [use Node.js debugging in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging)

Comment: It's not that clear to me how Node.js debugging in VS Code could help me debug on an android device, but i'll try the other examples and get back to you. Thanks.